# Tensorflow: How to set object recognition model input type to be float?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a object recognition model which only accepts `uint8` as an input type:

```
--input_layer type=uint8
```

I would like to change it to accept `float` as an input type.
Is there a way to modify the current model for this purpose, or make some changes in my training so my future models will have `float` as an input type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is this method `tf.cast(...)`, but I have no idea how to use it to modify my model.
If there is a way to fix my problem using it, an explanation would be very appreciated.

Note to moderators:
"Document your own continued efforts to answer your question."
That's in suggestions on how to make my question easier to answer, so please don't delete this